# What is difference in several styles for proc syntax in tcl?

Tags: syntax, tcl

May I know how sytanx of proc affets on its working.
in context of

-Memory consumption

-Argument passing

-scope of proc (local/global)

```
proc dosomething {} {
   #code here
}

proc dosomething { } {
    #code here
}

proc dosomething {
    #code here
}

proc dosomething args {
     #code here
}

proc ::dosomething {} {
     #code here
}
```

And so on.....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They are mostly the same:

Defines a command with no arguments

```
proc dosomething {} {
   #code here
}
```

Same as above, defines a command with no arguments

```
proc dosomething { } {
    #code here
}
```

Not valid... should throw an error

```
proc dosomething {
    #code here
}
```

Defines a command with a variable number of arguments (ie, varargs)

```
proc dosomething args {
     #code here
}
```

Defines a command, in the top level namespace, with no arguments (same as the first two in most cases)

```
proc ::dosomething {} {
     #code here
}
```

There's no such thing as a local proc, btw. They can be inside a namespace, but all procs are global.